# I am attempting to route my Wlan wifi directly through my virtual machine before my actual local machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am attempting to route my Wlan wifi directly through my virtual machine before my actual local machine. I am doing this so I can use wireshark on my virtual machine without having packets be altered from my local Ubuntu machine in transit. I know that I could just install wireshark on Ubuntu, but I want to learn about routing and bridges anyway.

I tried setting up two bridges "outside" and "inside". My plan was to have outside>Kali>inside>Ubuntu. I was using `brctl` to achieve this, but seem to be running into an error: `can't add wlp0 to bridge outside: Operation not supported` when i run this command: `sudo brctl addif outside wlp0`

To get around this I needed to add an extra address on the wifi access point using `addr4`

I was using `brctl` to set up the two different networks, but I was getting an error when I tried to connect my wl0 network to outside. From my research it seems that is because the brctl command is for ethernet not wifi. I now needed to use the `iw` `4addr` command to give it 4 different addreses so it can be used as a bridge. then use the `ip link master` command. Now I am suck on how to get the different machines to use the bridges. I couldn't connect to wifi after setting up outside as master so i removed it (which didn't work). So I had to restart my pc, but now both outside and inside are missing from `ip a` [steps-linked-here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554331/theoretical-tap-interface-w-wifi-parent-interface/555676#555676)

Comment: This is not a good idea. NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant on the host need to send information to finish associating with the WiFi.

Comment: It depends: on [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) it is custom to have an own VM as firewall. I don't see why imitating this behavior on Ubuntu would be doubtworthy. I read the question as: how is it possible?

Comment: @zx485 Is this not safe? Or is it doable, but I need to download Qubes_OS? I have updated my question with some new information.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete how-to-do answer, but rather intended as an inspiration on what direction appears feasible.

My comment about [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) was intended to confirm: yes, this is possible, and even in a professional way. Qubes OS has achieved this. I used it for some time, but the usability suffered tremendously. I've been more busy configuring everything than doing actual work :-/

Qubes OS is based on Fedora Linux, so off-topic here. But Qubes OS proves that it can be done: using a VM as a firewall and only after network traffic has been processed by that VM, it reaches the core system.

The general path would be using [PCI-passthrough](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=PCI-passthrough) on your network interfaces. So IIRC you have to configure GRUB to ignore the PCI-IDs of your network card(s). I don't remember the details, but [here is a useful post](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=60531).

After you have made Ubuntu ignoring your network card(s), register and access them in your VM, process them with your firewall and other programs, and then pass the traffic back and forth to your Ubuntu instance, probably via a VIF(Virtual Interface) network adapter exposed by your network VM.

I haven't tested it (other than using Qubes OS, and the above is a little bit different), but this should only be a rough outline. If someone really could provide a complete guide on how to do this, this answer would become pretty obsolete.